# Is the end of Honey and Clover Season 2 the end of the series?

Tags: honey-and-clover

**Warning! Spoilers ahead.**

The final season of Chica Umino's *Honey and Clover* ended with Yuuta Takemoto eating a literal honey-and-clover sandwich made by his love interest Hagumi Hanamoto. He was crying as he ate it and said the lines (which made me tear up, just like the other moments of the series):

> I’d been wondering whether there is a meaning to a failed love… Is something that disappeared the same as something that never existed? But now I know there is — There was a meaning right here.. Because despite the heartbreak, I’m still glad that I fell in love with you.
>
> --Yuuta Takemoto ([read more](http://animequotes.net/honey-and-clover-quotes/#ixzz2mXLq8eWm))

I wonder if Umino made the end a cliffhanger, an open-ended one or if there is a theory out there in the Internets that could shed a light into this. Do you guys know anything post-season 2?

Comment: since it's adapted from a manga it could continue on in the manga like with Bleach

Comment: In case you aren't aware, Honey and Clover is based on [a manga](http://myanimelist.net/manga/1009/Hachimitsu_to_Clover) (which is now finished, with 64 chapters). I'm not sure how much of it was covered by the anime - according to [some guy on the internet](http://forums.animesuki.com/showthread.php?p=719064#post719064), the anime ended in the same way as the manga, so the end of season 2 might be the end of it all.

Comment: @senshin you could probably post that as an answer.